# Can I get an instance of a class that implements an interface?

Tags: java, interface

I have this function:

```
/***
 * Changes the windows panel and allows a state change
 * you can also change the minimum window size
 * */
public void changePanel(CBPanel panel){
    mainFrame.setContentPane();
    mainFrame.setMinimumSize(panel.getMinSize());
    mainFrame.setResizable(panel.canResize());
}
```

It takes `CBPanel` as the only argument and `CBPanel` is interface that generally will be implemented onto a `JCOmponent`. Is there any way I can get an instance of the `JComponent` from interface class?

I call it like so

```
changePanel(new LoginPanel());
```

So logically, I should be able to get an instance of the `LoginPanel`, right? I was wondering if it does using some kind of type declaration of type cast?

Comment: What do you mean by 'get an instance of the JComponent from interface class'? What do you want to do? Do you want to call methods on a `JComponent` instance that `CBPanel` doesn't have?

Comment: say I pass in LoginPanel as an argument, how can I get an instanceof LoginPanel from that, so I can pass it into the mainFrame.setContentPane(); function?

Comment: `mainFrame.setContentPane()` doesn't have an argument.

Comment: It will do, when I find out the answer to my question :P

Comment: Because it is unclear what you are asking and you make no effort to clarify your problem. Again: What do you want to do?

Comment: I didnt, but I guess because the question is very unclear. Do you imply that `LoginPanel` extends `JComponent`? Could you write in pseudo code what you intend to do?

Comment: I want to get an isntance of the class that's implementing CBPanel once it has been used in the function, I'm passing LoginPanel into the function as a parameter but I cannot retrieve any of the variables stored within the LoginPanel  class because It's a CBPanel that the function takes! I'm sorry I have difficulty explaining things sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have

```
public class LoginPanel extends JComponent implements CBPanel {
    // ....
}
```

You can do

```
public void changePanel(CBPanel panel){
    JComponent jComponent = null;
    if(panel instanceof JComponent) {
        jComponent = (JComponent) panel;
    }
    // if you want LoginPanel then you can cast it to it if it is a subtype of it
    LoginPanel loginPanel = null;
    if(panel instanceof LoginPanel ) {
        loginPanel = (LoginPanel) panel;
    }
    mainFrame.setContentPane();
    mainFrame.setMinimumSize(panel.getMinSize());
    mainFrame.setResizable(panel.canResize());
}
```

But you have to figure out what to do if the `CBPanel` you are passing is neither a suntype of `JComponent` nor `LoginPanel`.

Comment: So it's as simple as a type cast?

EDIT: Works perfectly, exactly what I was looking for. thank you very much.

Comment: @ShaunWild If my assumption is correct, then yes. but always use `instanceof` check and act accordingly to not get an `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If your method has an argument type as a reference of an interface called `CBPanel` then this method can accept the object of any class implementing this interface. So if `JComponent` implements `CBPanel` then you your method `changePanel` will accept it.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but I want to then get an instance of the JComponent that is passed into it as an argument.